# Django exclude from queryset if all attributes of the set not match

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 models Course and Class

[image: model]

I'm trying to exclude the courses where **ALL** his classes vacancies are 0, but this query is excluding the course if only one of the class vacancies is 0.

```py
 courses = Course.objects.all().exclude(class_set__vacancies=0)
```

Classes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a Queryset containing a list of all the courses where there is at least one vacancy in any associated class, try this:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(class__vacancies__gte = 1).distinct()
```

You don't need `_set` in your `filter()` argument; when the call is made to the database, its joining the `Course` and `Class` tables anyway.

As I think you know, but I'll point out for the sake of clarity, `__vacancies` is Django's shorthand way of representing a field in a related table; in this case, the related table is the `Class` table, and the related field is `vacancies`.

The `__gte` in `.filter(class__vacancies__gte = 1)` is "greater than or equal to", so basically this function gets a list of all the `Course`-`Class` combinations where there is at least one vacancy in the class, then returns just the `Course` object.

If you had a `Course` with two `Classes`, and both `Classes` had vacancies, `Course.objects.filter(class__vacancies__gte = 1)` would return duplicate `Courses`. I'm assuming you just want a list of the Courses with open classes, and thus duplicates are undesirable. In order to remove the duplicates, you need to include `.distinct()`.

`.distinct()` can be tricky though, depending on your specific use case. See the Django docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct